# How to write a grammar that every 0 is followed by at lease one 1 in Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

How to write a grammar that every $0$ is followed by at lease one $1$. I can't quit figure it out. By the way, what does $S\rightarrow(0?1)$* do? especially the question mark? Thank you !!

Comment: You look like you're writing regular expressions, but I've never seen regular expressions mixed with the usual notation for context-free grammars. What exactly is the structure you're writing?

Comment: It is just regular expression.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page for regular expressions, search on the word "marked" to find a table of syntax. http://regexr.com is pretty neat too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a context-free grammar for the language you describe, assuming the alphabet is $\{0,1\}$:
\begin{gather}
S \rightarrow ST1\ |\ \epsilon\\
T \rightarrow 0\ |\ \epsilon\\
\end{gather}

This allows you to recursively build any string, by beginning with the variable $S$. Variable $S$ can be replaced with an empty string, or $S$ followed by $T$ followed by $1$. It's easy to see that if the string does contain a $0$, that $0$ will be directly followed by a $1$. Note that $\epsilon$ represents the empty string.

This context-free-grammar corresponds to the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `L = (0?1)*`. The `?` mark means that there is at most one occurrence of the previous character (zero or one `0`s). The `*` operator means that the expression within parentheses is repeated zero or more times. This regular expression describes exactly what you did in your question: the language of strings for which all occurrences of `0`s are followed by at least one `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is a part that I don't understand. According to your grammar, then S would never derive to any terminal except empty string. T can be derived to 0. But S will just keep going until it hits empty string. Do you mind if you could explain that part so that I can understand more? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps a derivation of the string 11011 will help, which is clearly valid. $S \rightarrow ST1 \rightarrow S1 \rightarrow ST11 \rightarrow S011 \rightarrow ST1011 \rightarrow S1011\rightarrow ST11011 \rightarrow S11011 \rightarrow 11011$.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer.